# Hadoop S3-driver 403 error after few sucessfull requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3, nutch

I'm using AWS S3 driver with Apache Nutch to upload files to S3 bucket from EC2 instance. There is IAM policy attached to EC2 to allow to access S3 bucket:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:ListBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::storage"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::storage/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

It's working fine at the beginning: Nutch parses segments and write it to S3 bucket, but after few segments it's failing with error:

> Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: ..., AWS Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, AWS Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 403, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: ..., AWS Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, AWS Error Message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method., S3 Extended Request ID: ...
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.copyObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1507)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyCallable.copyInOneChunk(CopyCallable.java:143)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyCallable.call(CopyCallable.java:131)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.copy(CopyMonitor.java:189)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.call(CopyMonitor.java:134)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.CopyMonitor.call(CopyMonitor.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[ERROR] org.apache.nutch.crawl.CrawlDb: CrawlDb update job did not succeed, job status:FAILED, reason: NA
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: CrawlDb update job did not succeed, job status:FAILED, reason: NA
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.CrawlDb.update(CrawlDb.java:142)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.CrawlDb.update(CrawlDb.java:83)
```

I suppose that IAM policy is OK, since Nutch can upload few segments before failing.

My AWS Hadoop related config is:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true
fs.s3a.endpoint=s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
```

Why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

---

Update:
I'm running Nutch programmatically (not from CLI) on single EC2 machine (not Hadoop cluster), to access S3 I'm using `s3a` filesystem (the output path is `s3a://mybucket/data`).
Hadoop version is `2.7.3`, Nutch version is `1.15`.

Comment: Could you share more information about your environment? Version of Nutch, Hadoop version and distribution, running Nutch in local or (pseudo-)distributed mode, etc. From the stack I guess you're not using the [s3a filesystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#S3A)?

Comment: @SebastianNagel sure, just updated the question

Comment: 1. "programmatically" - could be the reason if it means that a S3 client is kept for a long time. From CLI will start a new process for every job, in distributed mode every task is run in a separate process.
2.  you also might to try a newer Hadoop version because S3A has seen lot of improvements recently.

Comment: @g4s8 any suggested work around? I'm stuck with the same issue on the same version of Hadoop as yours.

Comment: @Nandeesh this issue is reproducing in local mode only, I've started small AWS EMR Hadoop cluster and successfully uploaded to S3 from it

Answer (score 1):

Because of S3 Inconsistency side-effects the above error will appear when running in local mode.

> Since S3 provides only eventual consistency on read-after-write, there is no guarantee that when listing the files, or trying to rename a file, it will exist in the S3 bucket even though it has just been previously written.

Hadoop team also provides this troubleshooting guide: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/site/markdown/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.md

If your use-case need to be run in a local-mode I would suggest the following work-around:

1. write the files to `local-folder`
2. use `aws s3 sync local-folder s3://bucket-name --region region-name --delete`